# What kind of questions should we ask on Meta Stack Overflow and on Meta Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, meta, mso-mse-split, scope

What kind of questions should we ask on Meta Stack Exchange (MSE) and what kind of questions should we ask on Meta Stack Overflow (MSO)?

Are we going to continue to ask questions regarding the workings and policies of Stack Overflow on MSO or should we post the same on MSE?

Comment: Time to setup meta.meta.stackoverflow.com?

Comment: There will be a blog post going up tomorrow morning / afternoon. Short version: Ask on your own meta site, we'll handle migrations as needed. If you're sure the conversation belongs on MSE you're welcome to go there, but you don't _have_ to.

Comment: I'm aware, I was making a joke because we are asking questions about the site where we ask questions about the site

Comment: If it's site specific, go to meta.site.com. If it's a question that applies (or could apply) to every site, go to meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: So many "meta" discussions, keep mis-reading as "meat". I now want steak and it's 11am. What.

Comment: metaception? :P

Comment: I never meta.stackoverflow question I didn't like.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### MSO

- Retagging
- SO specific features (adjusted number of reviews required, etc.)
- SO design
- Anything concerning SO, and only SO

### MSE

- Special stuff ([Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) / [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/tour) / [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) (SEDE))
- Anything about changing the whole SE system, not just for one site.
- Meta.meta.* as long as it spans across multiple metas (there's still a [meta](/questions/tagged/meta) tag for each meta site)
- Anything regarding multiple sites

Basically, MSO is for SO, and MSE is for SE.

Comment: By this logic, isn't the OP wrong on MSO and should be moved to MSE? I'm just curious...

Answer (score 26):

Treat Meta Stack Overflow like you would any other child meta site - if your question is specific to *this* community, then ask it here. Think of this like Town Hall.

Meta Stack Exchange is the capital city, where we discuss things that all of our communities have in common (our engine, the bugs it has from time to time and the features folks want out of it). There's also questions about Stack Exchange as a company, the philosophy behind building our sites, etc.

You *don't* have to go to MSE unless you want to, the community team and your moderators will take care of handling migrations for you, as they're needed.

Put simply, MSE isn't something you even need to know about or think about, unless you want to.

Comment: "Treat Meta Stack Overflow like you would any other child meta site" How many users will find this statement useful? I suspect most Stack Overflow users would wonder what a child meta site even *is*.

Comment: If that is the case Tim why are all the questions I've asked been imported to SE meta instead of SO meta when I specifically tagged them  [tag:stackoverflow]?

Comment: @Lankymart Because we're still in the process of migrating posts, many of which I'm sending over today. However, it's not going to be a _whole_ lot, I'm shooting for stuff that basically fell through the cracks. It's going to be probably a week before I say I'm "done" migrating things over.

Comment: @TimPost Cool, thanks for clarifying. If questions are tagged [tag:stackoverflow] is there a good chance they will end up here?