# Missing tag suggestions when the corresponding tags are already there

Tags: bug, tags

I typed `"sort"` into the tag box, and got the following:

[image]

Then I added the [sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sorting) tag, and tried again, and got a missing spot in the suggestions:

[image]

And it's not like there's any shortage of tags to pick from:

[image]

It seems like a bug - can we fix it?

If it's by-design, can we change it?

Comment: Kind of minor, but eh, why not

Comment: Shouldn't this be in MSE, it's common to all of SE?

Comment: @Barmar As far as I'm aware, we can just post everything to a child Meta site as long as the issue relates directly to that site as well. ["You don't have to go to MSE unless you want to, the community team and your moderators will take care of handling migrations for you, as they're needed."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250073/1711796)

Comment: Oh, that's nice of them :)