# Does my SO/Stylebot question belong on SO meta?

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation

I haven't had much attention come to my question, [SE FONT SCALING: stylebot: sidebar cover comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966505/stylebot-sidebar-cover-comments).  Is it possible I've posted it in the wrong place?

On Stack Overflow, as seen in the image in my question, comments are covered by sidebar links.  It's very annoying.  I can't read the comments due to the sidebar.  I want to use StyleBot to correct it, as you can clearly see in the question (link below).  Because the question is strongly related to SO, I wonder if it belongs in Meta.SO or on SO.

Comment: So you're saying that a custom style on top of SE's styles isn't working and want us to fix that? Isn't that kind of off-topic?

Comment: @bjb568 I'm saying SE's default style isn't working, and I'm trying to find a custom style bot solution.

Comment: @bjb568 Off topic for what site?  I think you're just trying to push an idea that doesn't fit.  I'm asking where the question belongs.  Is it Superuser--because it's about customizing software--, for stackoverflow--because it's CSS-related--, or for meta--because it's site-related?  It's not a question of if it's on-topic because it is.  It's a question of which site its most on-topic at.

Comment: @bjb568 According to this answer: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250020/what-kind-of-questions-should-we-ask-on-meta-stack-overflow-and-on-meta-stack-ex/250066#250066, it appears the question is well-suited for meta.  Now, who answered that question....  Why--  Oh my, it appears to be you!

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 but your question isn't really about Stack Overflow.  It is about modifying the SE styles for your personal needs.  Since it is essential a programming question, SO is the better place for it in my opinion.  However, because you are trying to modify SO, [StackApps](http://stackapps.com/) may also be appropriate, but unfortunately, I am not active on StackApps, so I don't know specifically that the question would be on-topic as written or not.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thanks.  If I took Stylebot out of the equation, do you think it would fit so meta or se meta?  Respectfully, it seems like something somebody would want to fix: it looks very amateur.  If you click 'show/add more comments' or 'add comment' or 'edit comment', then a 10th of the comment vanishes behind other text and links.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 in general, either MSO or MSE would be fine.  With only a few exceptions, the SE team has said you can always last on the local meta site and if necessary, it will get moved.  However, this depend on the actual problem.  If the issue is caused by a 3rd party app or browser extension/add-in, an unsupported browser, or personal modifications then it wouldn't be on-topic anywhere.  If the problem is 100% caused by the site, then it would be on-topic.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Well, if it's caused by any of the things listed (and I'm not saying it is), then it's caused by a "personal modification".  I set the font scaling to large in Chrome.  But why should I make it difficult to view all other sites, just so I can view sites on SE?  It seems that SE should simply account for this problem.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 changing the font size wouldn't quite qualify as a personal modification.  That is a browser feature.  So I'd suggest asking as question on MSO and clearing explain what is wrong, what you have done that may have caused it.  Tag it as a bug.  But given it is a limit use-case since it would appear that few users would encounter this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved.  See: [SE FONT SCALING: stylebot: sidebar cover comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966505/stylebot-sidebar-cover-comments).

You can use

```
tr td textarea {
  width:475px;
}
```

[*edit pending].