# Is there a limit to how many downvotes a question can get?

Tags: support, questions, downvotes

Are there any limits to how many downvotes a question can get? Normally when someone downvotes them they also vote to close. Suppose no one votes to close.

If someone gets *n* amount of downvotes, will that question automatically get closed?

Comment: You want us to try for this one? :p

Comment: See also on meta se: [Maximum upvote and downvote a question or answer can receive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178418)

Comment: @TemaniAfif haha, I thought downvotes count differently for meta though

Comment: The questions that require a close-vote often also deserve a downvote. But not always.

Comment: We don't know. [We've never gotten to the limit without biting](https://youtu.be/2IA5Cv_5-g8?t=17)

Comment: @L_Church: Can we *not*?  I get that this post is memetic, but the question *is* legitimate and not unfair.  Not sure why everyone's piling on the downvotes.

Comment: @L_Church, please tell me why this question is "So Sad"?  Is it common knowledge that all StackExchange site must behave the same, or can each site have minor differences in behavior?  Also, Makoto answered this question correctly, and has not posted any "memetic" comments.

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/857357

Comment: Of course there's a limit, each user with more than 125 rep can only cast 1 downvote on any given question.

Comment: @rene I'm a bit dissapointed. This question is about how many downvotes a **question** can get but your SEDE query also shows answer.

Comment: @AndréKool you can't always win ...

Comment: @L_Church "Is this something to do with how StackOverflow works?" -- Yes, it is. Though it may be a general question about Stack Exchange, any answer to it is applicable to the mechanics of this site. [It is fine to ask this sort of question here, even if there is a cross-site dupe on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250073/2751851).

Comment: Found an interesting historic one with negative score of -147: [How to send 100,000 emails weekly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3905734/1287812)

Comment: @brasofilo I like how it's favorited by over 300 people

Comment: A question can have any negative score, which can be achieved when many people downvoted this question. This usually happens on famous, but rather controversial questions, as worse questions tend to get on hold or deleted altogether.

In my opinion, being mod-deleted is worse, and means that question genuinely received negative reception.

Comment: @brasofilo I like how it's tagged PHP! :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While the [linked Meta question in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178418/175248) answers the principal question - no, there is no limit to the number of downvotes a post can receive - I want to call attention to another part of your question.

> If someone get x amount of downvotes will the question automatically get closed?

Downvotes are *not* close votes, and close votes are *not* downvotes.  Applying one does not always imply that you will apply the other; that is, if I downvote a question, I may elect to *not* close it, or if I close a question, I may elect *not* to downvote it.

It is the case that they are very closely related, especially given that downvotes and close votes accompany one another on plenty of occasions, but **there is nothing in the system that will automatically *close* a question** because it has reached a downvote threshold.

A question *may* be [automatically ***deleted***](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/175248) subject to the rules of automatic deletion - which can be incredibly conservative - but I will stress that deletion is *not* the same as closure.

Comment: @Jo.:  Closing a question is not the same as *deleting* a question.  But that is a good point to make.

Comment: Nevertheless, even though many [or even most] downvoted questions are closed or deleted due to being completely unsuitable for the site, there are still a small number of questions with a large negative score. These questions are generally of a controversial nature in this site, or are historically significant. Since the Monica's incident, official SE posts reached downvote counts of over -1500.