# Is there (should there be) a work-aloud tag?

Tags: support, tags

I am a long time SO user and aware of the need to put a lot of effort into the form of the question.
There are some questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66232549/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-entityframeworkcore-when-calling-sta) (call it a rabbit hole question) where I find that I keep needing to refine the question. This can be frustrating to the people who try to help me.
Is there a tag I can use so my helpers are pre-warned?

Comment: @KirstenGreed Meta.SO means Meta Stack Overflow. You initially asked this on Meta Stack Exchange (AKA. Meta.SE) but it has since been migrated here. See: [What kind of questions should we ask on Meta Stack Overflow and on Meta Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250020/8967612)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem with such a tag is that it's [a meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/). Assuming you don't change your end goal, there's nothing *particularly* wrong with updating your question as you go along, especially based on requests for clarification in the comments. In fact, until such a point that someone feels it's answerable, I'd feel you would have quite a lot of leeway since you're not invalidating existing answers.

I would personally consider refining questions to cover things you tried and things that were in comments to be part of the natural lifecycle of the question, and explicit warnings of incompleteness are redundant.

As long as it's got enough details and clarity not to be closed, I'd say it's probably fine.